# Can I extract a Solution (WSP File) from my site level?

Tags: feature, export, solution

We have a Feature located on one of our SharePoint sites how can I export this feature (wsp) so that I can import it into another site?

Comment: Is the other site you mentioned in the same web application? If so, it must be able for the other site too!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following powershell

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$wsp = $farm.Solutions.Item("customsolution.wsp").SolutionFile
$wsp.SaveAs("c:\temp\customsolution.wsp")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract them from the site collection level, not a subsite.

They'd be located at `../sites/sitecollection/_catalogs/solutions/`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now if I could figure out how to close these questions.  :)

Comment: Below the up/downvote icons, there should be a "mark as answer" tick